# Location Update Issue iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I know there is a lot of questions related to that,But I cant able to link with my Issue. In my app,I am fetching the Nearby Restaurant,Initially,If user clicks on 'Nearby' button I fetch the lat,long,placemark details,Using this code below.

```
-(void)setUpUserLocation
{
    BOOL locationAllowed = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
   if (locationAllowed==NO)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No authorization"
        message:@"Please, enable access to your location"
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
        otherButtonTitles:@"Open Settings", nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;

        if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
            [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location=[locations lastObject];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];
        NSDictionary *addressDictionary = [placemark addressDictionary];

    }];
    [self stopSignificantChangesUpdates];

}
- (void)stopSignificantChangesUpdates
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager = nil;
}
```

My Question is, If the user location changes, how do I give the user an alert like `Your location changed, you need to update it then only you can get a Nearby Restaurant` `Location popup should come once the user location changes` otherwise don't want to call the `didUpdateLocation` everytime.  I called `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` then it did not called the didUpdateLocation in first time itself.Any Help on this.

Comment: Sorry, I dont fully understand the question. Do you want to show the user an alert informing them that their location has change and thus they need to update the app to find a nearby restaurant? If your user's location changes you can recalculate the location to the restaurant. Now if you absolutely need to do this, then just do it on didUpdateLocation with an accuracy that makes sense to your case. if you use SignificantLocationChanges, the location manager will only inform you if the location has changed significantly (usually a couple hundred meters)

Comment: Ya Thanks, If user's location changes then again, I need some popup to show user tells that your location changes with `allow` & `don't allow` button.If they pressed allow then update new location. and also u mentioned that `SignificantLocationChanges` can u help me out this one i didnt know that.                                                           locationManager.desiredAccuracy =kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;

Comment: Is there any delegates to find that,User are within the Hundred meters of that location or else they reached...Its helpful for me to call the webservice based on that

Comment: Have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/ Here You can find information about how iOS handles location changes, you can use the significant location changes by calling startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges which i think you have tried. On regards to the alert, you can use a UIAlertController.

Comment: with Siginificant Location Changes your location manager will call the didUpdateLocation method of your delegate, you should already have this in place for what i understand.

Comment: Ya I tried called Siginificant Location Changes instead of startupdatelocation but it did not called the startupdate location.what can I do.Ok thanks for your link reference.But page not found can u edit agin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113800/discussion-between-shangari-c-and-daniel-ormeno).

Answer (score 2):

check after some time or check after user's movement(whatever you want),if condition is true then call service...

I think it help you;

**Step 1**

```
 (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
//set the amount of metres travelled before location update is made
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:100];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]; 

// call the timer with 5 minutes cap using 5 * 60 = 300
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300.0f target:self selector:@selector(sendlocation1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

**Step 2**

Every 100 Meter change Device This Method is called :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude);

    NSLog(@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    CLLocationDistance meters = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
         if(meters >=100)
      {
         // call webservice for location is updated 
         [self sendlocation1];
      }else
      {
       // call normal method
       }
    }
```